# Access the variables of a component

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to access a component variable. This variable is modified by an html input.

Here is my current code

Parent :

```
<template>
   <component>Child</component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
          dataChild : '',
    }
</script>
```

Child :

```
<template>
    <input type="text" name="data" v-model="data" class="form-control">
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
          data: ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I've looked all over the internet but nothing works on my side or I'm doing wrong :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like below:

**Parent**

```
<template>
    <component @input-child="childData"></component>
</template>
<script>
import Component from "@/components/Component";
export default {
   components: { Component },
   data() {
       return {
      dataChild: ""
   };
},
methods: {
    childData(data) {
       console.log(data);
      // you can assign it to dataChild variable
   }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<template>
<input
    type="text"
    name="data"
    v-model="data"
    @input="$emit('input-child', data)"
    class="form-control"
 />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            data: ""
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately it shows me mouseevent and not the data.

Comment: in parent you can see console log and assign it to parent data and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to send data from child component to parent in vue is to emit that inside child and listen for event inside parent. Like this:

Child:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({ dataChild: 'TEST' }),
  methods: {
    send () {
      this.$emit('data', this.dataChild)
    }
  },
  mounted () { this.send() }
}
```

Parent:

```
<div>
  <child @data="get"></child>
</div>


export default {
  data: () => ({ data: '' }),
  methods: {
    get(value) {
      this.data = value
    }
  }
}
```